# Errors with foreach and array

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, foreach

Hi I'm using foreach to insert into my database multiple authors for a book.

Here is the foreach:

```
foreach ($_POST["authors"] as $author) 
{
    $sqlAuthor = "INSERT INTO book_author (book_ISBN, author_ID)
        VALUES('$isbn','$author')";

    mysql_query($sqlAuthor);
}
```

I am getting the authors with a `select multiple` from my page for which I have created a function to display in the `select multiple` the authors available.

The code is producing exactly what I want it to produce in the page from my database (the names of all the authors)

Here is the `multiple()` function:

```
<?php include ("includes/connections.php");
    function multiple($intIdField, $strfNameField, $strlNameField, $strTableName, $strOrderField, $strNameOrdinal, $strMethod="asc") {
       echo "<select multiple=\"multiple\" name=\"$strNameOrdinal\[\]\">\n";

       $strQuery = "select $intIdField, $strfNameField, $strlNameField
                   from $strTableName
                   order by $strOrderField $strMethod";

       $rsrcResult = mysql_query($strQuery);

       while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsrcResult)) {
          $strA = $arrayRow["$intIdField"];
          $strB = $arrayRow["$strlNameField"] . " " . $arrayRow["$strfNameField"];    
          echo "<option value=\"$strA \">$strB</option>\n";
       }

       echo "</select>";
    }
?>
```

Now for some reason it throws the following errors:

`Notice: Undefined index: authors in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex\addBook.php on line 63`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex\addBook.php on line 63`

I think it tells me that it can't find the `authors` array but I find it very strange

Here the php code inside the html to call the `multiple()` function:

`<?php multiple("author_ID", "author_firstname", "author_lastname", "author", "author_lastname", "authors"); ?>`

Anyone has any idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799); you can use instead either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML that your code is generating to make sure it's producing what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use foreach nest it in an if:

```
if (count($_POST["authors"])) {
    foreach ($_POST["authors"] as $author)  {
       ...
    }
}
```

so if you have 0 element in the array, or it's not an array (string, null, anything else) you won't enter the if, and won't get the error on foreach's wrong parameter

Comment: the if just checks for empty array, my problem is that even if I select the authors I want it is still an empty array

Comment: @SilliconTouch, what does var_dump($_POST["authors"]) display when you have 2 elements selected and posted?

Comment: it displays this: `array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "10 " [1]=> string(2) "1 " }`

Comment: Jesus! I found it, the extra space after each identity was making it to not work

Comment: strange. and there was the error in line 63 also when you had things selected??? BTW you have spaces after the numbers: "10 ", "1 ", that might cause you another problem later, so fix it as well

Comment: you see! that's why we use var_dump :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So to get this straight, why would a simple space just make everything not work? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you try to use it in this SQL: VALUES('$isbn','$author'), so you try to insert "10 " to a column that's possibly integer, and "10 " is a string

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
echo "<select multiple=\"multiple\" name=\"{$strNameOrdinal}[]\">\n";
```

and also check if its set before using it as others suggested.

Edit: Not related to the issue on hand but you have an extra space after `$strA`, change to if it wasn't on purpose.

```
echo "<option value=\"$strA\">$strB</option>\n";
```

Comment: I tried it and it did not work, also I left the if out on purpose and even after choosing authors it still show the error that "authors" is undefined. So even if I choose the authors it is still not defined. Very weird

Comment: I suggest you use http://validator.w3.org/ to validate your html and then firebug (or any alternative) to check what's being posted.

Comment: I left the if statement out, that way it will show an error when the array is empty even if it should be not

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing the notice and error because `$_POST["authors"]` isn't defined or there are no authors.

Simply use `if(isset($_POST["authors"])) {` to make sure data has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
foreach ($_POST["authors"] as $author) 
{
```

to this:

```
foreach ((array)$_POST["authors"] as $author) 
{
```

to make it **empty-safe**.
Also i cannot see from where the "authors" are sent to **addBook.php** to make a suggestion..